# Can we connect Microsoft Azure Bot to Azure SQL Database and read data from the DB and use it as a reply for the Bot?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am working on a ChatBot project, which requires to query from a table in SQL database hosted in Azure and use the result as a reply for the bot.

I am using a basic bot template from Azure Web App Bot. Independently without connecting to the database, the Bot is working fine. And there is no issues with the database, I was able to query from the same DB using EF DB first approach in a MVC webapp.

But in the project, if I use the same approach, I am getting an error: ***connect ECONNREFUSED***

And the Bot is not able work or connect in such a case.
Can anyone help me resolve this issue, or if I can get a detailed document to develop a bot which can query and interact to Azure SQL database should also work.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A bot using the BotBuilder SDK is generally just a web application.  Please share the code you are trying to use to connect to the database.

Comment: So just to give more details, lets say I already have a SQL table. Now I want my bot using Microsoft Bot Framework to connect to the same. And as you had mentioned, it is just a web application, I should be able to use EF db first approach which is very common in MVC web apps, and after fetching the query, I want my bot to reply that as an answer.

Comment: So I tried with a similar approach, but the problem that I am facing when I am trying to connect to the database, through the basic bot code (the template which I was able to download as a zip from Azure) was throwing the connect ECONNREFUSED error. I am not sure, if I am doing it correctly, if you post any blog/article or documentation link for solving this, that would be helpful.

Comment: It is no different from connecting to a database in any web application. All of the Web App bot templates in Azure are using the Bot Builder SDK, and are just web applications. It sounds like a firewall issue, or something is wrong with the connection string.

Comment: Have you seen this document:[Saving Bot Activities in Azure SQL Database](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/05/Saving-Bot-Actions-On-Azure-Sql-Server/)?Can it helps you?

Comment: Looks promising. Although with the latest version of the SDK, I think things have changed a little bit, but let me try this one. Thanks @LeonYue

Comment: @AajeBaaje You‘re welcome, waiting for your result.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AzureSql) you will find a simple example of how to connect to Azure SQL Database from a Bot and insert data.

To use Azure SQL, please configure the Autofac Dependency Injection in Global.asax. Particularly the following is the piece of code that configures injection of Azure Sql Storage:

```
var store = new SqlBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BotDataContextConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
builder.Register(c => store)
    .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
    .AsSelf()
    .SingleInstance();
```

The connection string to Azure SQL Database should be in the web.config:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BotDataContextConnectionString" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        connectionString="Server=tcp:[YourDatabaseServerName].database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=[YourDatabaseName];Persist Security Info=False;User ID=[YourDatabaseUserId];Password=[YourDatabaseUserPassword];MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Please make sure to configure [Azure SQL Database firewall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#manage-server-level-ip-firewall-rules-using-the-azure-portal).

[image]

Comment: SqlBotDataStore is for using sql server for Bot State.  This user is simply trying to query sql server, not necessarily use it for state.  Your note about the firewall seems valid though. +1 for that part.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Alberto
But as Eric has pointed, I want bot to query from an sql db and reply back the result as an answer to a particular question/intent. From whatever documentation I tried to refer, people have used blob storage or cosmos db to store or query results through bot. I wasn't able to find anything on querying sql db through webapp bots