# How to connect Bot framework with analysis services like SQL server analysis service or Azure analysis service?

Tags: botframework, ssas, azure-analysis-services

I am new to AS can Any one say me how to Connect Bot Framework v4 with SQL server analysis service or Azure analysis service ?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve? Is it to manage the user and conversation state?

Comment: hi @ranusharao, it is to fetch some data from AAS and display it in bot using DAX queries

Comment: It is more related to how the Azure AAS works. You can either directly use the AAS API to fetch the data and then display it in the bot or else connect the bot to the AAS by the means of [OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell)(Azure AD app) and fetch the data and display in the bot. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824671/can-we-connect-microsoft-azure-bot-to-azure-sql-database-and-read-data-from-the) question to get started with.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: Hi @ranusharao, thanks for your answer.but i want to connect to a cube of AAS from Bot ,how ever i have solved it by creating a function app of framework and i have used adomd.net to connect  that cube and perform operation.